# How secure is this method?

Tags: php, mysql, ios, security, webserver

I want to select data from a MySql database on a iphone device. The method I seem is the easiest one is to connect to a php file with GET arguments and then return it as a string.

Now Im just wondering what the chances are someone will find the IP-adress and the file and use it from another place than the app.

Comment: It doesn't matter if someone finds the file. Do Basic authorization to access your PHP file. Also to care about sql use [prepared statement](http://us3.php.net//manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Look into [oAuth](http://us1.php.net//manual/en/book.oauth.php), so the app has to auth with your back end before it can access any data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- use basic http auth request like:

```
curl -u username:password http://yourWebPage
```

2- and then use basic http auth response like:

```
$username = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
$password = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];

if($username == $correctUsername AND $password == $correctPassword){
   //do some thing 
}else{
  header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
  header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
  die ("Not authorized");
}
```

3- and then send your data in the body of http post as json string

4- Receive the posted data in php file:

```
$myData = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

Comment: How does I use the "curl -u username:password http://yourWebPage"? I tried adding it in an NSString and change the yourWebPage ofc, but it doesnt seem to work. If I try to get the $_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"] it gives me an error "Undefined index".

Comment: @Arbitur I give you CURL as example but you should do it from your  iphone device as CURL do.
$_SERVER["PHP_AUTH_USER"] it give you an error "Undefined index"  because there is no any basic http requist from iphon

Comment: I found a good tutorial how to do it on ios :)

Comment: @Arbitur Okay if your tutorial like what I said, please give vote up or correct answer :)